# Javascript - pushing Elements with same Class into array & using each in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, push

I have various elements with same class (cCameras). I am able to push the elements into the empty array but for some reason I cannot access the elements inside the array.

```
var eCamerasArray = [];

// elements in this class are being pushed into the array 'cCameras'
$(".cCameras").each (function (){ eCamerasArray.push (this); }); 

// Firebug gives me an array with elements inside.
console.log (eCamerasArray);

for( var i = 0; i < eCamerasArray.length; i++) {    
   // Firebug gives me [undefined].
   console.log (eCamerasArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just doing `$(".cCameras")` gets you a jQuery wrapped array of DOM elements, which you can access through the `get` method. No need to build up the array yourself.

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/EygTk/

Comment: Using your code seems to work in Chrome and Firefox for me. http://jsfiddle.net/47yMd/. Are the elements defined?

Comment: Thank you guys, toArray() did it. 

I need the array for looping & modifying purposes. Cheers

Comment: Not working for me, I did copy & paste here :!

Comment: @Esailija, would you please post an answer so I can pick as the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write `$(".cCameras").toArray()` to get the same result, possibly one that works.